# Lists, Loops, Average Python

Tags: python, list, loops, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm currently having an issue with my code. The program works properly but for some reason when I enter all positive numbers I receive an error for the last function. The last function is removing all the negative numbers from the list.

```
i=0
numList = []
x = int(input("Please enter number from -9999 to end:"))
while x > -9999:
    i = i + 1
    numList.insert(i,x)
    x = int(input("Please enter number from -9999 to end:"))
    if x == -9999:
    print("The list of numbers entered:",(numList))

newList = numList[:]
secList = numList[:]

def posNumAvg(newList):
    for e in newList[:]:
        if e < 0:
            newList.remove(e)            


def negNumAvg(secList):
    for y in secList[:]:
        if y > 0:
            secList.remove(y)            

posNumAvg(newList)
negNumAvg(secList)
mydict = {'AvgPositive':(sum(newList)//len(newList)),'AvgNonPos':     (sum(secList)//len(secList)),'AvgAllNum':(sum(numList)//len(numList))}
print("The dictionary with averages is:",mydict)
```

Comment: What error are your getting?

Comment: Then the program *doesn't* work properly :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compute the average of an empty list, which is not defined (specifically, the list's length is zero so you end up dividing by zero).

You need to decide what you want to do in that case and handle it specifically.

As an aside, you can rewrite

```
for e in newList[:]:
    if e < 0:
        newList.remove(e)
```

as

```
newList = [e for e in newList if e >= 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

NOte: Never modify the list when you iterating over it. Let me make some changes to your code

```
numList = []
while True: 
    x = int(input("Please enter number from -9999 to end:")
    if x == -9999:   
        print("The list of numbers entered:",(numList))
        break
    # you don't need i here, used append to insert element at last of list
    # insert is used to insert a element at specific position
    numList.append(x)

def posNumAvg(gotList):
    list_negative = []   # will contain negative number
    for e in gotList:
        if e < 0:
            list_negative.append(e)
    return list_negative

def negNumAvg(gotList):
    list_positive = []   # will contain positive number
    for y in gotList:
        if y >= 0:
            list_positive.append(y)            
    return list_positive

list_positive = posNumAvg(numList)
list_negative = negNumAvg(numList)
mydict = {'AvgPositive':(sum(list_positive)//len(list_positive)),'AvgNonPos':     (sum(list_negative)//len(list_negative)),'AvgAllNum':(sum(numList)//len(numList))}
print("The dictionary with averages is:",mydict)
```

you can get positive and negative number from one function: see this code

```
def neg_poss(gotList):
    list_positive = []   # will contain positive number
    list_negative = []   # will contain negative number
    for y in gotList:
        if y >= 0:
            list_positive.append(y)            
        else:list_negative.append(y)
    return list_positive,list_negative

list_positive,list_negative = neg_post(numList)
```